# repeat variable values according to dataframe shape

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, csv

I have a variable `TS` with shape 540,20 and my dataframe is of shape 660,20.
I want to repeat values of `TS` in the order so that it can match shape of dataframe and add it as last column of dataframe. I want to shape it according to shape of dataframe even if shape of dataframe changes. My solution is not working
`TS` values are like this `1.718206999999999951e+01 1.701339000000000112e+01 1.670511400000000179e+01 1.590475700000000003e+01`

```
TS = data[data.keys()[9]] 
    TS = np.array(TS)
    
    rpts = np.shape(data)
    TS1 = np.repeat(TS,rpts[:1])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `np.tile()` on the last column and then use `np.hstack()` on it to concatenate it to the end:

```
import numpy as np

ts = np.array([[1, 2], [4, 5], [5, 6]])
ts1 = np.hstack((ts, np.tile(ts[:, [-1]], 3)))

print(ts)
print(ts1)
```

Which would give you:

```
[[1 2]
 [4 5]
 [5 6]]

[[1 2 2 2 2]
 [4 5 5 5 5]
 [5 6 6 6 6]]
```